# disambiguate function with default parameter

Tags: c++

I always thought of default arguments as syntactic sugar for overloading.
But it seems like they are just glued on top of a single function (type) – the one without any of them supplied.
Is there a good reason why that’s the case?

```
void foo(int i);// void (*)(int)
void foo();// void (*)()
void bar(int i = false);// void (*)(int)

int main() {
    return static_cast<void(*)()>(&foo) // works
        && static_cast<void(*)()>(&bar);// doesn’t work
}
```

Comment: The function type for `bar` is `void(int)` even though it has a default argument. It is not equivalent to an overloaded function.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I want to know why it’s designed to be inequivalent?

Comment: So that you can declare a function without a default argument, and define it with one later. (e.g `void f(int) ... void f(int i = 0) {...}`). It's useful to not have to write the default argument over again.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You have that backwards. The default needs to be on the declaration not the definition.

Comment: @KurtStutsman It can be on either one.

Comment: @0x499602D2 No it can't. It has to be visible at compile time for a source module. If the definition is not #included into that file, the default will not be used because the compiler will not know about it.

Comment: @KurtStutsman You're assuming the declaration/definition are separated by a header and source file, I was not.

Comment: That’s the funny part I wasn’t really aware of. The value itself is a definition which is probably why it can’t be part of the declared function type. But it would be nice if you could get the compiler to give you a different type based on the availability of said definition.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely they are treated differently.

```
void foo(int i);// void (*)(int)
void foo();// void (*)()
```

These calls are resolved at link time, the linker will link them to different function because they are different function.

```
void bar(int i = false);// void (*)(int)
```

It is resolved at compile time, the compiler will add the extra parameter if you do not provide one, and all calls will be linked to the same function.

As it is the compiler who adds the extra parameter, so the compiler must know the default parameter, it has to be visible at compile time.

Example code:

```
% cat t.cpp
void foo(int i);// void (*)(int)
void foo();// void (*)()
void bar(int i = false);// void (*)(int)

int main() {
    foo(0);
    foo();
    bar(0);
    bar();
}
```

Compile result:

```
% objdump -C -r t.o

t.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
000000000000000a R_X86_64_PC32     foo(int)-0x0000000000000004
000000000000000f R_X86_64_PC32     foo()-0x0000000000000004
0000000000000019 R_X86_64_PC32     bar(int)-0x0000000000000004
0000000000000023 R_X86_64_PC32     bar(int)-0x0000000000000004


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.eh_frame]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000020 R_X86_64_PC32     .text
```

There are foo() and foo(int), but only bar(int) no bar().

Comment: But the compiler could – theoretically – also generate an additional function, even if it’s only in the event of a `static_cast`.